# Three.js - Under what conditions are THREE.Lines frustum-culled?

Tags: three.js

I'm drawing a handful of lines (THREE.Line). Under some conditions, the line suddenly disappears from the screen. This happens frequently when one endpoint is far outside the camera's field of view, but the other one is definitely within the field of view. This also happens when the line crosses the camera's field of view, but both endpoints are far outside it.

I can temporarily fix it by setting frustumCulled to false for each line, but this isn't optimal since I might have thousands of lines in the scene.

Is this working as expected?

BTW, I'm using r68. I haven't had time to refactor my app to work with r69. I'm using the WebGLRenderer.

Comment: 1. Would you be interested in tracking that down? If so, search for `frustum.intersectsObject( object )` in `WebGLRenderer.js`. I would not be surprised if there is a logic bug there if the bounding sphere is large. 2. Can you rewrite your code to have one line, so there is just one drawcall, and set `frustumCulled` to `false`? 3. I assume you are using `WebGLRenderer`.

Comment: 1. I can take a look. Should I first check whether this issue happens with r69? 2. I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. 3. I am using WebGLRenderer. I'll edit the post to include that.

Comment: You will want to use the development version r.70dev.

Comment: Thousands of line objects results in thousands of drawcalls. (Type renderer.info into the console.) Optimally, you want one drawcall. Google `THREE.LinePieces`.

Comment: I found the problem. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a user error. I'm changing the positions of the endpoints when I click and drag them. I then set the geometry.verticesNeedUpdate to true so that the change is picked up. The problem is that the new bounding sphere is not computed. Is that my fault? Or is that something that should be done automatically? Based on this tutorial:https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Drawing-lines, I'd say it's a bug since there is no boundingSphere updating going on here.

Comment: Sorry, the link in the previous comment was the wrong one. I guess I don't have evidence that it's not a user error, then.

Answer (score 0):

I needed avoiding lines to dissapear too.

Following Justin idea of frustumCulled I had to do

```
line.frustumCulled = false;
```

I thought it was

```
line.geometry.frustumCulled = false;
```

but I was wrong, you've to apply it on the line not on its geometry.

This works for me on version 0.70

Comment: Otherwise, if you want the objects to be frustum culled call :


`this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();`


on the line geometry when it is updated( or created ). Tested in 0.73.

Comment: I can confirm that the bounding sphere seems to be used in frustum culling! It needs to be updated after the geometry changes.