# Meshes culled after buffer geom vertex positions updated

Tags: three.js

Some objects are being frustrum culled after I amend their buffer geometry vertex positions. I don't want to set `frustrumCulled = false`, nor can I (feasibly) change the mesh position to anything other than (0,0,0). What options do I have here? My expectation is that the meshes should behave consistently with each other. I'm obviously missing something here.

Demo:

- 2 Meshes, one green, one red
- Green mesh is initialised with position `0,0,0` with vertices around `0,10,0`
- Red mesh is initialised with position `0,0,0` with vertices around `0,0,0`, but after 2 seconds, vertices are updated to around `0,10,0`
- Orbit controls allow zooming (Just zoom in see see actual behaviour)
- Expected behaviour: Both meshes are visible when I zoom / move the camera. Or at least, they both behave in the same way
- Actual behaviour, green mesh behaves as expected, red mesh is sometimes culled

```js
const OrbitControls = THREE.OrbitControls // CDN shim

// Helper to create mesh with buffer geom
const createGeo = (initialY, color) => {
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
  const vertices = new Float32Array([
    0, initialY, 0,
    0, initialY + 1, 0,
    0, initialY, 1,
    0, initialY, 0,
    0, initialY + 1, 0,
    1, initialY, 0
  ])
  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: color,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  })
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  // Note: Setting frustumCulled to false always allows this to be seen, but I don't this object to always be seen
  // mesh.frustumCulled = false

  scene.add(mesh)
  return mesh
}

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)
let controls
const greenMesh = createGeo(10, 0x00FF00) // Set Green at 0,10,0
const redMesh = createGeo(0, 0xFF0000) // Set red at 0,0,0, then update to 0,10,0

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  controls.update()
  greenMesh.rotation.y += 0.1
  redMesh.rotation.y -= 0.1
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
camera.position.set(15, -20, 15)
controls.target.set(0, 10, 0)
window.onresize = function() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
}

scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(100))

// Update red mesh to same position as green mesh
setTimeout(() => {
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(0, 0, 10, 0)
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(1, 0, 11, 0)
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(2, 0, 10, 1)
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(3, 0, 10, 0)
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(4, 0, 11, 0)
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(5, 1, 10, 0)

  // As per - https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things
  redMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true
  redMesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
  // When zooming / panning, red mesh is not always visible
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you should add `redMesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere()` after the `computeBoundingBox` call - it is seems to do the trick and it's recommended [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things) especially in connection with culling. I also found relevant [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806768/three-js-under-what-conditions-are-three-lines-frustum-culled) and especially at the "I found the problem" and other comments.

Comment: Yep... I included the creation of the bounding box, but it looks as though you have to compute both the bounding box and sphere. Whilst this is in the docs and I linked to it in the demo, it would be good to clarify the reason why this is the case

Comment: I suppose that's how they implemented it and we have to comply. We can verify in the source code  1) that the two methods [`computeBoundingBox`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f11d6e872d6b4fd12b6b2c3b8457756556ab0353/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L290) and `computeBoundingSphere` are independent (one doesn't call the other) and 2) Both the bbox and bounding sphere are needed, e.g., in [Frustum](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f11d6e872d6b4fd12b6b2c3b8457756556ab0353/src/math/Frustum.js) methods `intersectsObject`, `intersectsBox`, etc.

Comment: ... It is indeed interesting to explore why you can get away without computing the bounding sphere if culling is disabled, but I suppose it's a safer bet in most cases to call both functions.

Comment: Yep. More answers here. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/boundingsphere-and-boundingbox/17868/2 If you want to add a quick 1 line answer, I'll accept, else I'll just add an answer later, but much appreciated. Whilst I haven't used threejs for a number of releases, I don't remember bounding spheres, but it is in the docs and I assumed that out was required to use the box our the sphere, but alas, both are required for culling

Comment: It's alright then; please write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @kikon, both

```
mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
mesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere()
```

are required. Whilst it doesn't ***explicitly*** state these in this [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things), they have to both be used when updating vertex positions (I had made the incorrect assumption that you would use either the box or sphere).

The [code for frustrum culling](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Frustum.js#L65) uses the bounding sphere, and a bounding sphere is automatically created once first invoked (hence the difference in red / green mesh behaviour), and has to be recomputed and both methods need to be called in this case.